# How to refactor this? ^^

Tags: c#

Hi I have a "dumb" question. Here is my problem:

```
string ct=ctx.Request.ContentType;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ct))
{
  ct=new ContentType(ct).MediaType;
  if (!ct.Equals(KnownMimeType.Json, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || !ct.Equals(KnownMimeType.Xml, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
  {
    RespondWith(Status.BadRequest, "!json or xml");
    return;
  }
}
```

With the conditional Operator when an XML is sent the if body is executed which shouldn't be the case.
This is my current solution but the code with the empty method bodies is horrible. :/

```
string ct=ctx.Request.ContentType;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ct))
{
  ct=new ContentType(ct).MediaType;
  if (ct.Equals(KnownMimeType.Json, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) { }
  else if (ct.Equals(KnownMimeType.Xml, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) { }
  else
  {
    RespondWith(Status.BadRequest, "!json or xml");
    return;
  }
}
```

The goal is that every Content Type except JSON and XML should be responded with Status.BadReqeust
What can I do to refactor this?

Thanks from a newbie.

Comment: You might want to check [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) on how you can rewrite your `if()` condition and how you will see that it might not make any sense.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I think that does the opposite of what the OP wants. You want `if (!ct.Equals(KnownMimeType.Json, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) &&  !ct.Equals(KnownMimeType.Xml, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {    RespondWith(Status.BadRequest, "!json or xml"); `

Comment: Got it @lurker.... Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You two are right. Of course I need the  && operator because if both are not true than the BadRequest should be sent. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
if (!(ct.Equals(KnownMimeType.Json, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || ct.Equals(KnownMimeType.Xml, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))) {    RespondWith(Status.BadRequest, "!json or xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

//For the sake of brevity and readable code.This may be your solution

```
string ct=ctx.Request.ContentType;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ct))
{
  ct=new ContentType(ct).MediaType;
  var isJson = ct.Equals(KnownMimeType.Json, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
  var isXml =ct.Equals(KnownMimeType.Xml, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    
  if(isJson || isXml)
     continue;
  else  
     return RespondWith(Status.BadRequest, "!json or xml");  
}
else
     return RespondWith(Status.BadRequest, "Invalid content type"); 
     //Maybe you can change status code instead of BadRequest for invalid content type


private Result RespondWith(Status status,string message)
{
}

//I assume that you return a dto like this
public class Result
{
    public Status Status;
    public string Message;

}
```